# Qt, MySQL: QMYSQLResult::data: column 1 out of range that only happens sometimes

Tags: mysql, qt

I have the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_trigger` (
 `triggerid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `trigelems` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `trig_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`triggerid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `trigelems` (`trigelems`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Table of all active trigger setups'
```

I run the following query on it:

```
SELECT triggerid FROM tb_trigger WHERE trigelems='0:0 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:40000 6:10000 7:50000 8:99999 9:1 10:1 11:0'
```

This is done using the following QT code:

```
QString db::fetchString(QString sqlQuery) {

    QSqlQuery res = QSqlQuery(sqlQuery, sqldb);
    if (!res.next()){
        return "None";
    } else
        return res.value(0).toString();
}
```

The problem is, once in a while (maybe 1 times out of 100), I get a `QMYSQLResult::data: column 1 out of range` error on this query. When I check the database afterwards for the exact same query it failed on, it DOES return a row. This leaves me quite dumbfounded.

This application is a long-term running daemon. Maybe that could be a factor? Would checking `res.record().count()` help in this case?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with query execution? Try doing the query in two steps instead one: `QSqlQuery res=QSqlQuery(sqldb); if(!res.exec(sqlQuery)) return "Error in exec"; //the rest of your code` It looks like there is a problem with query execution (maybe your sqlQuery included "'" sign where it shouldn't or something else) I'd also suggest using q.first() in case you want only first record instead of q.next()

Comment: I can only guess this is an intermittent problem in the driver, because https://forum.qt.io/topic/130962/column-1-out-of-range-although-datas-aren-t-missing-and-data-are-showing-properly seems to report the same issue as you do.